# Close menu with jquery when clicking outside of the menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to add an event with j-query where the user clicks outside the menu it animates slides the menu and closes the overlay opacity. Instead of using event.stopPropagation(); I would like to this:
Jquery

```
$(this).click(function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).closest('').length) {
            $("").hide();
        }
    });
```

I want to use this code in my jquery somehow.
Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/2a4y4uds/2/

A little new to j-query so bear with me

Comment: you can use a library if that is fine for you!
I use this one: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use variables.

EDIT3 think i have fixed the bugs now.

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2a4y4uds/7/)**

```
var menuopen = false;
var menuclicked = false;


    function animatemenu(){
        if (!$(".c-menu--slide-left").hasClass("Moved")) {
            $(".c-menu--slide-left").animate({
                "left": "0px"
            }, "slow").addClass("Moved");
            $(".menu-overlay").fadeToggle("slow");
            setTimeout(function(){ menuopen = true;}, 100);
           // alert("open");
        } else {
            $(".c-menu--slide-left").animate({
                "left": "-300px"
            }, "slow").removeClass("Moved");
            $(".menu-overlay").fadeToggle("slow");
           setTimeout(function(){ menuopen = false, menuclicked = false;}, 100);
            //alert("close");
        }
    }


$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".menu").click(function () {
    animatemenu();
    menuopen = false;
  });

  $("#c-menu--slide-left").click(function () {
    //alert("menu");
    menuclicked = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ menuclicked = false;}, 1);
  });
});



$(document).click(function() {
        if (menuclicked == false){
            if (menuopen == true) {
                animatemenu();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much it. Just the bugs are annoying, it closes and opens twice and when you click inside the menu it closes it.

Comment: I updated the the jsfiddle demo I just added another menuopen = false; think that should fix the open twice bug.

Comment: Nice it worked. Is there anyway to keep the menu from closing if someone clicks inside the menu div.

Comment: Have updated the jsfiddle demo and code once more think that should fix the clicking on the menu issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
// click anywhere hide the menus if it is visible
$('html').click(function(event) {
    if ( $('#menu').is(':visible') ) {
        var re = new RegExp("menu_div");
        if (!event.target.id.match(re) ) {
            $('#menu').hide();
        }
    }
});
```